# Makefile modification to support c++11

Tags: c++, makefile, c++11

I am able to compile a single file using gcc with -std=c++0x option. But I can't do this through makefile. Here are the set of flags in my makefile (which after make complains about c++11 keywords):

```
MACHINE = $(shell echo `uname -s`-`uname -m` | sed "s/ //g")
CCC     = CC
CCC     = g++
CFLAGS  = -O3
CFLAGS  = -std=c++0x
CFLAGS  = -pg -D_DEBUG -g -c -Wall
LFLAGS  = -O
LFLAGS  = -pg -g
```

What am I missing?

**Edit**:
I changed it to the following, but I still get compile errors, which I don't get with command line gcc invocation.

```
CXXFLAGS=-O3 -std=c++0x -pg -D_DEBUG -g -c -Wall
```

Comment: You probably want `CFLAGS += stuff`, not `CFLAGS = stuff`.

Comment: Why do you have several CFLAGS? Why not just "CFLAGS=-O3 -std=c++0x -pg -D_DEBUG -g -c -Wall"?

Comment: I changed it to the following, but I still get compile errors, which I don't get with command line gcc invocation.

CXXFLAGS=-O3 -std=c++0x -pg -D_DEBUG -g -c -Wall

Comment: What is the command line that gets printed when g++ is called? What are the errors that you get?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This way your makefile will use all of your `CFLAGS`:

```
CFLAGS=-O3 -std=c++0x -pg -D_DEBUG -g -c -Wall
```

You're overriding them with each "CFLAGS=..." declaration.

Moreover, it should be `CXXFLAGS`, not `CFLAGS`. `CFLAGS` is for C applications.

As @Florian Sowade said, you could use `CFLAGS += -O3 -std....` (or CXXFLAGS..), so that users can provide their own flags when executing make.

Comment: If you write `CFLAGS += ...` the user can give his own CFLAGS with `CFLAGS="..." make`

Comment: @FlorianSowade great, added that to the answer ;)

Comment: Florian: that's not true.  Variable assignments on the command line override settings in the makefile completely, even += style settings.  The best (and most portable) way to handle this is to use a different variable for internal flags and leave `CFLAGS` / `CXXFLAGS` for the person invoking make.

Comment: +1 for `CXXFLAGS`! That funky thing foncused me into a state of foncusion #NoTypo

Answer (score 3):

You can keep it in multiple lines, but you probably want to *append*, not to *assign*:

```
# e.g.
CFLAGS  += -O3
CFLAGS  += -std=c++0x
CFLAGS  += -pg -D_DEBUG -g -c -Wall
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get that mess from? That makefile was wrong long before you modified it for C++11.

Let's start with the first line:

```
MACHINE = $(shell echo `uname -s`-`uname -m` | sed "s/ //g")
```

Try running the command `` echo `uname -s`-`uname -m` `` and you'll see if has no spaces in anyway, so what's the point in the `sed` command?

Maybe you want this:

```
MACHINE = $(shell uname -s -m | sed "s/ /-/g")
```

That only runs two processes (uname and sed) not four (two unames, echo and sed)

If you're using GNU make it should be

```
MACHINE := $(shell uname -s -m | sed "s/ /-/g")
```

So it's only run once.

```
CCC     = CC
```

What is `CC`?

```
CCC     = g++
```

Oh, it doesn't matter, you've replaced the value anyway.
The conventional make variable for the C++ compiler is `CXX`

```
CFLAGS  = -O3
CFLAGS  = -std=c++0x
CFLAGS  = -pg -D_DEBUG -g -c -Wall
```

As others have pointed out, you set CFLAGS, then set it to something different, then to something different. Only the last value will be kept.

```
LFLAGS  = -O
LFLAGS  = -pg -g
```

Same here, and what is `LFLAGS`? Do you mean `LDFLAGS`?

A good way to debug makefiles is to create a target to print out the variables you are setting, to check they have the values you expect:

```
print-vars:
        echo CFLAGS is $(CFLAGS)
        echo LDFLAGS is $(LDFLAGS)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is a huge legacy code base, and I didn't really bother to modify the makefile until now that I needed to enable C++11. I have fixed the problem with overwriting flags as is shown in my edit.