# Makefile - C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile

I'm trying to understand MakeFiles and I'm trying to set the CFLAGS to C++11 in my make file. I have read the following: [Makefile modification to support c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787126/makefile-modification-to-support-c11) I have implemented one of the solutions, however, it does not seem to work, I'm getting the same error:

> error: ‘i’ does not name a type
>        for(auto i=begin; (i != end); i++)

Here is my MakeFile:

```
# Location of the Python Header files 
# This is system dependant. 

PYTHON_VERSION = 2.7
PYTHON_INCLUDE = /usr/include/python$(PYTHON_VERSION)

CFLAGS += -03
CFLAGS += -std=c++0x
CFLAGS += -pg -D_DEBUG -g -c -Wal
# location of the Boost Python include files and library

BOOST_INC = /usr/include
BOOST_LIB = /usr/lib

WAV_TARGET = /includes/Wav
WAV_SOURCE = Wav

# Compile the .wav Python and Cpp file 

$(WAV_TARGET).so: $(WAV_TARGET).o
  g++ -shared -Wl, --export-dynamic ($WAV_TARGET).o -L$(BOOST_LIB) -lboost_python -
          L/usr/lib/python$(PYTHON_VERSION)/config -lpython$(PYTHON_VERSION) -o  
          $(WAV_TARGET).so
$(WAV_TARGET).o: $(WAV_SOURCE).cpp
 g++ -I$(PYTHON_INCLUDE) -I$(BOOST_INC) -fPIC -c Wav.cpp
```

I'm probably missing something really stupid, but where am I going wrong here?

Comment: What vwersion of GCC are you using?

Comment: The flag should be `-std=c++11` and what's the `gcc` version?

Comment: Hey @Manu343726 I'm using version 4.8.1

Comment: @Phorce you are using GCC 4.8.1, so as Kiril pointed out, that flag should be `-std=c++11` instead of `-std=c++0x`.

Comment: That `-03` is zero-three, should be `-O3` with the letter O.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your target isn't even using `CFLAGS` when invoking `g++`.  You can either add `$(CFLAGS)` to the target:

```
$(WAV_TARGET).o: $(WAV_SOURCE).cpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -I$(PYTHON_INCLUDE) -I$(BOOST_INC) -fPIC -c Wav.cpp
```

Or just add `-std=c++11` to the flags you listed:

```
$(WAV_TARGET).o: $(WAV_SOURCE).cpp
    g++ -std=c++11 -I$(PYTHON_INCLUDE) -I$(BOOST_INC) -fPIC -c Wav.cpp
```

Comment: When I add C++11 I get the following: /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected make: *** [/includes/Wav.so] Error 2

Comment: What exactly did you add and where?

Comment: Just like your example, I added the  -std=c++11 after the g++ also, tried with $(CFLAGS)

Comment: `CFLAGS` is typically used for c-programs, use `CXXFLAG` for c++ programs.